# add class using id method

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass, removeclass

I currently have this code (this is the only code in the js file)

```
if ($('body').hasClass('home')) { 
('#home_link').addClass('home').removeClass('test_class')};
```

I'm trying to add a `home` class to a `li` item with id `home_link` if the `body` has a class home and remove `test_class` in the process.

(Doesn't seem to work, all help would be appreciated)

Comment: Can you explain your situation. Maybe you can do it at different way what you want? I mean instead of adding and removing a class to your `body` element.

Comment: body element could be anything, i just want to add a class to a <li> item with a perticular ID - the class being added is different for each page so logically we chose the unique body class for each page

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net of your problem?  That would make it much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: (i kept it simple to focus on addClass first) here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/66zye/

Comment: it works at jsfiddle - i think the issue is with my site and not the js code

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing a `$`:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('home')) 
{ 
    $('#home_link').addClass('home').removeClass('test_class');
}
```